# How to a add a footnote at the bottom of a table generated with pander::pander

Tags: r, pander

I know that `caption="namehere"`   can be used to add a title, but now I´d like to know how to a add a footnote at the bottom of a table generated with `pander::pander`, in order to indicate the source from where the data was obtained.

Comment: I'm not aware of a markup placing footnote at the bottom of the table ... but you can add normal footnotes in a grid table just like at any other part of the document.

Answer (score 1):

pandoc.footnote("your footnote here") at the end of the code chunk where the table is produced in markdown. It's not pretty but at least the placement is correct, and can perhaps be styled to your liking in the final document.